# Cannot get access to inner class variables

Tags: java, oop, nested, inner-classes

I cannot get access to variables in object of inner class "listPanel".
There is variable "tutajcos" but I cannot get access from other methods in CosView class.

What is a problem? Eclipse does not prompt me anything

```
package cos.view;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Observable;

import util.Model;
import util.View;

import javax.swing.*;

import cos.controller.CosController;
import cos.model.CosModel;

public class CosView extends View implements ActionListener {

    private JPanel buttonsPanel;
    private JPanel listPanel;
    private CosModel theModel;
    private CosController theController;

    public CosView(CosController theController, CosModel theModel) {
        this.theModel = theModel;
        this.theController = theController;

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                buildGui();
            }
        });
    }

    private void buildGui() {
        setTitle("Program GUI");
        listPanel = new ListPanel();
        buttonsPanel = new ButtonPanel();
        add(buttonsPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(listPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        pack();
        setVisible(true);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(400, 600);
        registerWithModel(theModel);
    }

    class ButtonPanel extends JPanel {

        JButton refreshButton = new JButton("Refresh");
        JTextField adresField = new JTextField("tutaj link", 10);

        public ButtonPanel() {
            refreshButton.addActionListener(CosView.this);
            add(refreshButton);
            add(adresField);
        }
    }

    class ListPanel extends JPanel {
        JTextField tutajcos;

        public ListPanel() {
            tutajcos = new JTextField(8);
            add(tutajcos);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String action = e.getActionCommand();
        theController.processUserAction(action);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
        System.out.println("Updating interface");
        if (o instanceof CosModel) {
            String content;
            //there is a problem-------------
            listPanel.tutajcos.setText("siema");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is not with access modifiers but rather with inheritance. Your `listPanel` variable is declared to be of type `JPanel` which has no accessible fields named `tutajcos`.
In order to be able to access it the way you try, you need to declare listPanel as ListPanel:

```
private ListPanel listPanel;
```

or cast it before call:

```
((ListPanel)listPanel).tutajcos.setText("siema");
```